# error loading rss feed stream null

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss

im creating an rss feed in my android app.
I however keep occuring this error.

Here is my logcat error...

```
03-12 14:04:04.025: E/RSS ERROR(4808): Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> null //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-12 14:04:04.285: I/dalvikvm(4808): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-12 14:04:04.305: I/dalvikvm(4808): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-12 14:04:04.335: D/ViewRootImpl(4808): pckname = com.tmm.android.rssreader
03-12 14:04:04.485: D/libEGL(4808): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-12 14:04:04.525: D/libEGL(4808): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-12 14:04:04.535: D/libEGL(4808): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-12 14:04:04.575: D/OpenGLRenderer(4808): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Can anyone help? im new to RSS feeds

Im not sure what part of the code im getting an error in, any suggestions?

```
package com.tmm.android.rssreader.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;


public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // Feed and Article objects to use for temporary storage
    private Article currentArticle = new Article();
    private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

    // Number of articles added so far
    private int articlesAdded = 0;

    // Number of articles to download
    private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 15;

    //Current characters being accumulated
    StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

    /* 
     * This method is called everytime a start element is found (an opening XML marker)
     * here we always reset the characters StringBuffer as we are only currently interested
     * in the the text values stored at leaf nodes
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#startElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.xml.sax.Attributes)
     */
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
        chars = new StringBuffer();
    }

    /* 
     * This method is called everytime an end element is found (a closing XML marker)
     * here we check what element is being closed, if it is a relevant leaf node that we are
     * checking, such as Title, then we get the characters we have accumulated in the StringBuffer
     * and set the current Article's title to the value
     * 
     * If this is closing the "Item", it means it is the end of the article, so we add that to the list
     * and then reset our Article object for the next one on the stream
     * 
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article title: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString());

        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
        {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article description: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString());
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
        {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article published date: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setPubDate(chars.toString());
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded"))
        {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article content: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
        {

        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
        {
            try {
                Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article link url: " + chars.toString());
                currentArticle.setUrl(new URL(chars.toString()));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("RSA Error", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        // Check if looking for article, and if article is complete
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

            articleList.add(currentArticle);

            currentArticle = new Article();

            // Lets check if we've hit our limit on number of articles
            articlesAdded++;
            if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT)
            {
                throw new SAXException();
            }
        }
    }


    /* 
     * This method is called when characters are found in between XML markers, however, there is no
     * guarante that this will be called at the end of the node, or that it will be called only once
     * , so we just accumulate these and then deal with them in endElement() to be sure we have all the
     * text
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#characters(char[], int, int)
     */
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }

    /**
     * This is the entry point to the parser and creates the feed to be parsed
     * 
     * @param feedUrl
     * @return
     */
    public List<Article> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            url = new URL(feedUrl);

            xr.setContentHandler(this);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler IO", e.getMessage() + " >> " + e.toString());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler SAX", e.toString());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler Parser Config", e.toString());
        }

        return articleList;
    }

}
```

---

NEW LOGCAT LOG FOR RECODED RSS READER

```
03-12 16:01:13.882: W/System.err(5792): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.cnn.com": No address associated with hostname
03-12 16:01:13.882: W/System.err(5792):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
03-12 16:01:13.912: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at com.exercise.AndroidRssReader.AndroidRssReader$MyTask.doInBackground(AndroidRssReader.java:43)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at com.exercise.AndroidRssReader.AndroidRssReader$MyTask.doInBackground(AndroidRssReader.java:1)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-12 16:01:13.922: W/System.err(5792):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-12 16:01:13.932: W/System.err(5792):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-12 16:01:13.932: W/System.err(5792):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-12 16:01:13.932: W/System.err(5792):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-12 16:01:13.932: W/System.err(5792): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
03-12 16:01:13.952: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
03-12 16:01:13.952: W/System.err(5792):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
03-12 16:01:13.952: W/System.err(5792):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:411)
03-12 16:01:13.962: W/System.err(5792):     ... 22 more
```

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace from this instead of just the ending error message and also the part of the code that is causing the exception?

Comment: Please post the code used to parse the RSS feed.

Comment: I don't see any stack trace in that logcat output.  You'll be looking for something with the tag `AndroidRuntime` and it'll be an error or `E` level log message.  If you're using eclipse, it typically shows up in red.

Comment: Ive no idea whats wrong, the app opens but the rss feeds dont appear??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> null //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This means you call your xml parsing in the UI thread. The xml parsing itself gets the data via `url.openStream()` in `getLatestArticles()`. Use an AsyncTask to parse your xml and publish the result after you finished.

Comment: Ive recoded some of the project, im using Async but im still getting no feed. il post the logcat log above.

Comment: 1. please just post the stack trace and not the entire logcat the next time. 2. the current error means, that you seem to have trouble connecting to cnn.com. Have you made sure that you have the internet permission set and that your emulator/device can connect to the internet? (and please keep in mind that technically, you totally asking a new question here... next time create a new one...)

Comment: Yes permission is in the manifest,tablet is connected to wifi. Sorry about the new question @warrenfaith

Comment: and the rest of my comment?

Comment: sorry hit enter by accident

Comment: Im following this tutorial for rss feeds - http://android-er.blogspot.ie/2012/07/rss-feeder-reader-run-in-asynctask.html               if it helps

Comment: No because you still don't answer my questions in the comment. Can your device access the domain you are requesting in your app?